# How can i convert dynamic variable - foreach into Parallel.ForEach()

Tags: c#, foreach

How can I convert this `foreach` into `Parallel.ForEach()`,

We are using `dynamic` variable to get outlook contacts.

Any help?

```
List<ServiceReference1.Addressbooks> list = new List<ServiceReference1.Addressbooks>();
// dynamic Contacts = outlook.GetNamespace("Mapi").GetDefaultFolder(10);
try
{
    dynamic Contacts = outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(10);
    foreach (var items in Contacts.items)
    {
        try
        {
            ServiceReference1.Addressbooks ad = new ServiceReference1.Addressbooks();
            ad.FirstName = (string)items.FirstName;
            ad.JobTitle = (string)items.JobTitle;
            ad.MobileTelephoneNumber = (string)items.MobileTelephoneNumber;
            ad.BusinessTelephoneNumber = (string)items.BusinessTelephoneNumber;
            ad.BusinessFaxNumber = (string)items.BusinessFaxNumber;
            ad.Email1Address = (string)items.Email1Address;
            ad.Body = items.Body.Length > 999 ? (items.Body).Substring(0, 999) : items.Body;
            ad.CompanyName = (string)items.CompanyName;
            ad.LastModificationTime = (DateTime)items.LastModificationTime;
            list.Add(ad);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            throw exp;
        }
    }
}
catch
{
}
return list;
```

Best Regards,
Prasanth.k

Comment: What are you having problems with?

Comment: Converting foreach to Parallel.ForEach gives me an error:\

Comment: Error: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type

Comment: and what is that error?

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach(((IEnumerable)Contacts.items).Cast<dynamic>(), item => { /* you code */})`, but better post the code, where you're trying to call `Parallel.ForEach`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this code and let me know your issue

```
Parallel.ForEach(Contacts.items, items =>
            {
                try
                {
                    ServiceReference1.Addressbooks ad = new ServiceReference1.Addressbooks();
                    ad.FirstName = (string)items.FirstName;
                    ad.JobTitle = (string)items.JobTitle;
                    ad.MobileTelephoneNumber = (string)items.MobileTelephoneNumber;
                    ad.BusinessTelephoneNumber = (string)items.BusinessTelephoneNumber;
                    ad.BusinessFaxNumber = (string)items.BusinessFaxNumber;
                    ad.Email1Address = (string)items.Email1Address;
                    ad.Body = items.Body.Length > 999 ? (items.Body).Substring(0, 999) : items.Body;
                    ad.CompanyName = (string)items.CompanyName;
                    ad.LastModificationTime = (DateTime)items.LastModificationTime;
                    list.Add(ad);
                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    throw exp;
                }
            });
```

Comment: tried this, Getting compilation Error: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type

Comment: instead of `Dynamic`, why don't you user `var`

Comment: var Contacts = outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(10);

                Parallel.ForEach(Contacts, line =>
                {
                    //update database
                }); Same error is coming at complile eime

Comment: refer this.. http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2010/08/04/dynamic-linq-a-little-more-dynamic.aspx may be helpful.

Comment: just to make sure.. Hope.. you are using .net 4.5 ? because Parellel.ForEach is available in c# 5 only..

Comment: @Bhaarat: `Parallel.ForEach` is available since .NET 4.0.